# Fastest way to sort in Python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, sorting

What is the fastest way to sort an array of whole integers bigger than 0 and less than 100000 in Python? But not using the built in functions like sort.

Im looking at the possibility to combine 2 sport functions depending on input size.

Comment: Why not use built in functions?

Comment: what's the fastest way to get to down the road but not driving that souped up Porsche?

Comment: What's the largest size the array might be?

Comment: @Anders: Don't reinvent the wheel. The built in sort() should suffice for your case.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to implement your own sorting routine? It smells like a homework assignment to me :-)

Comment: @Aaron - or more to the point - what's the fastest way down the road without using a pre-built vehicle of any kind ;)

Comment: @Rob Vermeulen You are right this is part of a homework assignment. Its not the entier task thats why i wanted to ask. We also have do do some extra metods for exstracting numbers form the array (we can use binary search since its sorted). I wanted to get a sence of where its good to start with the sorting. Im thinking of trying to implement an adaptiv sort witch is sort of like the sort() function i python where it uses one sort for small arrays and another for big arrays.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are interested in **asymptotic time**, then counting sort or radix sort provide good performance.

However, if you are interested in **wall clock time** you will need to compare performance between different algorithms using *your particular data sets*, as different algorithms perform differently with different datasets.  In that case, its always worth trying quicksort:

```
def qsort(inlist):
    if inlist == []: 
        return []
    else:
        pivot = inlist[0]
        lesser = qsort([x for x in inlist[1:] if x < pivot])
        greater = qsort([x for x in inlist[1:] if x >= pivot])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

Source: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Python

Comment: Good advice, except choice of variable list, which can cause nice errors. I post other, faster version.

Comment: Running the list comprehension twice over the same set of variables is probably also less than optimal.

Comment: @Tony Veijalainen “There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things”  -- I've changed the variable name

Answer (score 8):

Since you know the range of numbers, you can use [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which will be linear in time.

Comment: (I did not downvote).  Note that this is not a good algorithm if the array of integers is significantly smaller than 100000, as it will waste memory (and thus time) to construct the 100000 element list.

Answer (score 4):

Early versions of Python used a hybrid of `samplesort` (a variant of quicksort with large sample size) and binary insertion sort as the built-in sorting algorithm. This proved to be somewhat unstable. S0, from python 2.3 onward uses `adaptive mergesort` algorithm.

Order of mergesort (average) = `O(nlogn)`.
Order of mergesort (worst) = `O(nlogn)`.
But Order of quick sort (worst) = n*2

if you uses `list=[ .............. ]`

`list.sort()` uses `mergesort algorithm.`

For comparison between sorting algorithm you can read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

For detail comparison [comp](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216689.html)

Comment: it's timsort which is more adaptive than mergesort

Comment: Timsort is an adaptive, stable, natural mergesort.

Answer (score 4):

Radix sort theoretically runs in linear time (sort time grows roughly in direct proportion to array size ), but in practice Quicksort is probably more suited, unless you're sorting absolutely massive arrays.

If you want to make quicksort a bit faster, you can use insertion sort] when the array size becomes small.

It would probably be helpful to understand the concepts of algorithmic complexity and Big-O notation too.

Comment: When you say the array size becomes small do you mean less than 64 in size?

Comment: I'd say more about less than 10, but there's no right answer; the best idea is to experiment with different values and see which ends up faster.

Answer (score 3):

I might be a little late to the show, but there's an interesting article that compares different sorts at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sorting-efficiently-python-lakshmi-prakash

One of the main takeaways is that while the default sort does great we can do a little better with a compiled version of quicksort. This requires the Numba package.

[image]

Here's a link to the Github repo:
https://github.com/lprakash/Sorting-Algorithms/blob/master/sorts.ipynb

Comment: So default sort is kicking.

Answer (score 1):

We can use count sort using a dictionary to minimize the additional space usage, and keep the running time low as well. The count sort is much slower for small sizes of the input array because of the python vs C implementation overhead. The count sort starts to overtake the regular sort when the size of the array (COUNT) is about 1 million.

If you really want huge speedups for smaller size inputs, implement the count sort in C and call it from Python.

(Fixed a bug which Aaron (+1) helped catch ...)
The python only implementation below compares the 2 approaches...

```
import random
import time

COUNT = 3000000

array = [random.randint(1,100000) for i in range(COUNT)]
random.shuffle(array)

array1 = array[:]

start = time.time()
array1.sort()
end = time.time()
time1 = (end-start)
print 'Time to sort = ', time1*1000, 'ms'

array2 = array[:]

start = time.time()
ardict = {}
for a in array2:
    try:
        ardict[a] += 1
    except:
        ardict[a] = 1

indx = 0
for a in sorted(ardict.keys()):
    b = ardict[a]
    array2[indx:indx+b] = [a for i in xrange(b)]
    indx += b

end = time.time()
time2 = (end-start)
print 'Time to count sort = ', time2*1000, 'ms'

print 'Ratio =', time2/time1
```

Comment: +1  `Ratio = 1.16710428623` on my machine. clever use of a dict. It's worth noting though that changing the dict construction phase from `try: ardict[a] += 1; except: ardict[a] = 1` to `if a in ardict: ardict[a] += 1; else: ardict[a] = 1` drops the ratio to `Ratio = 0.696179723863` Sometimes (often) it is better to look before you leap.  I knew to do this because `try` is only cheaper than `if` if the exception rarely occurs. An actual exception is still very expensive.

Comment: unfortunately this algorithm is wrong. Try `array = [1,10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]`. The dangers of skating on undocumented implementation details strike again.

Comment: Thanks aaron - fixed the bug of not sorting the dict keys. That should slow it down a bit. However, it will preserve its almost O(n) nature if number of distinct elements compared to the array size is low.
I would love to see a 3D plot of distinct elements, array length as x and y dimensions and ratio of running time and the 3rd dimension. Maybe I will do it in a day or 2.

Comment: @Aaron: On my comp, the (try, except) works better. I coded it the (if then else) way first and switched to the (try, except) to speed up things. Also, the version with the bug removed runs faster than the previous one - because of the underlying C sort being used in sorting keys. Thats free beer right there. :-)

Comment: For me the except solution was also faster, little faster generation was by using tuple with generator if list is not necessary to produce (as it is mutable): `array2=tuple(a for a in sorted(ardict) for i in xrange(ardict[a]))`

Comment: Also doing `import blist
array = blist.blist(random.randint(1,100000) for i in range(COUNT))` has interesting effects especially for built in sort.

Answer (score 0):

The built in functions are best, but since you can't use them have a look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(l):
    p = 0
    while(p<len(l)-1):
        if(l[p]>l[p+1]):
            l[p],l[p+1] = l[p+1],l[p]
            if(not(p==0)):
                p = p-1
        else:
            p += 1
    return l
```

this is a algorithm that I created but is really fast. just do sort(l)
l being the list that you want to sort.

Comment: That's a bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

@fmark
Some benchmarking of a python merge-sort implementation I wrote against python quicksorts from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Python
and from top answer.

1. Size of the list and size of numbers in list irrelevant

merge sort wins, however it uses builtin int() to floor

```
import numpy as np
x = list(np.random.rand(100))


# TEST 1, merge_sort 
def merge(l, p, q, r):
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q
    left = l[p : p + n1]
    right = l[q + 1 : q + 1 + n2]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = p
    while k < r + 1:
        if i == n1:
            l[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        elif j == n2:
            l[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        elif  left[i] <= right[j]:
            l[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            l[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

def _merge_sort(l, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = int((p + r)/2)
        _merge_sort(l, p, q)
        _merge_sort(l, q+1, r)
        merge(l, p, q, r)

def merge_sort(l):
    _merge_sort(l, 0, len(l)-1)

# TEST 2
def quicksort(array):
    _quicksort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)

def _quicksort(array, start, stop):
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot, left, right = array[start], start, stop
        while left <= right:
            while array[left] < pivot:
                left += 1
            while array[right] > pivot:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                array[left], array[right] = array[right], array[left]
                left += 1
                right -= 1
        _quicksort(array, start, right)
        _quicksort(array, left, stop)

# TEST 3
def qsort(inlist):
    if inlist == []: 
        return []
    else:
        pivot = inlist[0]
        lesser = qsort([x for x in inlist[1:] if x < pivot])
        greater = qsort([x for x in inlist[1:] if x >= pivot])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater

def test1():
    merge_sort(x)

def test2():
    quicksort(x)

def test3():
    qsort(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print('merge_sort:', timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1, x;", number=10000))
    print('quicksort:', timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2, x;", number=10000))
    print('qsort:', timeit.timeit("test3()", setup="from __main__ import test3, x;", number=10000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bucket sort with bucket size = 1.  Memory is O(m) where m = the range of values being sorted.  Running time is O(n) where n = the number of items being sorted.  When the integer type used to record counts is bounded, this approach will fail if any value appears more than MAXINT times.

```
def sort(items):
  seen = [0] * 100000
  for item in items:
    seen[item] += 1
  index = 0
  for value, count in enumerate(seen):
    for _ in range(count):
      items[index] = value
      index += 1
```