# What is the fastest way to sort a large array of integers in python?

Tags: python

I want to sort an array of integers in python:

```
a=np.random.randint(0, high=1000000, size=1000000)
b = np.sort(a)
```

A faster way I found on [quora](https://qr.ae/pNPR7b) is

```
np.repeat(np.arange(1 + a.max()), np.bincount(a))
```

which is about 5 times faster on my machine. Anyone could come up with a better solution than the one on quora?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to sort in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855537/fastest-way-to-sort-in-python)

Comment: Nice. O(n) sorting! Hadn't heard of this one before. 'BucketSort' implemented as sorted cloning.

Comment: @Shradha No. It does not beat numpy.sort().